# Why am I referred to the manual page for "Arithmetic" when I type `?mgcv-faq` without `library(mgcv)`?

Tags: r

Well I spot this when I actually made a mistake. I want to get the manual page of `mgcv.FAQ`, but I

- forgot to do `library(mgcv)`;
- wrongly put `?mgcv-faq`.

But, R strangely directs me to the doc page as if I have done `?Arithmetic`.

What is going on? After I do `library(mgcv)`, putting `?mgcv-faq` now gives an error:

```
#Error in eval(argExpr, envir) : object 'mgcv' not found
#Error in .signatureFromCall(fdef, expr, envir, doEval) : 
#  error in trying to evaluate the expression for argument ‘e1’ (mgcv)
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

---

`sessionInfo()` before `library(mgcv)`:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

`sessionInfo()` after `library(mgcv)`:

```
## only shows what is different from the above

other attached packages:
[1] mgcv_1.8-24  nlme_3.1-137

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4  Matrix_1.2-14   tools_3.4.4     grid_3.4.4     
[5] lattice_0.20-35
```

I don't have Rstudio, so I run R in the terminal. And the manual page is displayed in the terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reproduce this with:

```
expr <- quote(mgcv-faq)
utils:::.helpForCall(expr, parent.frame())
```

`.helpForCall` gets called by `?` internally with this input.

Now, if the expression does not contain `::` or `:::` calls, `.helpForCall` extracts the symbol to look up by doing

```
expr[[1L]]
#`-`
```

without checking the length of the expression.

The `-` operator is first in the expression because the expression is parsed to function syntax.

Why does this happen? Because `?` should be able to handle `::` and `:::` in its input and nobody thought of handling a user error such as yours.

Comment: A lightening fast reply. I have also tried `?a-b`, `?a*b`, `?a:b`. It seems you are right. But why I got an error after  `library(mgcv)`. Nothing has changed to `expr`, hasn't it? In fact, after `library(mgcv)`, `?a-b` and `?a*b` return a similar error while `?a:b` still works.

Comment: That I can't see at a quick glance. The source code of `?`, `utils:::.helpForCall` and `utils:::.signatureFromCall` is not exactly easy to understand because of all these `if` conditions. You'll need to use the `browser` to find out how and why loading mgcv makes a difference.

Comment: This might actually be something that could be asked on the r-devel mailing list. They might even fix it.

Comment: However, consider the documentation in `help("?")`. Your input is clearly not documented as valid.

Comment: `help(mgcv-faq)` actually returns an error. The same for `help(a*b)` and `help(a:b)`. So `?` and `help` are different. They even have different manual page: `?"?"` and `?help`.

Comment: Well `help` doesn't support expressions with `::` or `:::`.